# PHP implode not getting passed

Tags: php, implode

I'm getting an error that says

> Warning: implode():Invalid arguments passed

I do not understand why it is so...

Here is my code.

```
if(isset($_POST['consultationbutton'])){        
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['selectedfile']['tmp_name'])); //SQL Injection defence!
    $checkedcondition = implode(",",$_POST['skincondition']);
    $checkedproduct = implode(",",$_POST['skincareinuse']);
    $consultquery="INSERT INTO counsel(nric,dateconsulted,editableface,skincarecurrentlyinuse,skincondition) VALUES('132','$_POST[storedate]','{$image}','$checkedproduct','$checkedcondition')";
    mysqli_query($dbconn,$consultquery);
}
```

`$_POST['skincondition']` and `$_POST['skincareinuse']` are the name of my checkboxes.

Comment: I gues that `$_POST['skincondition']` or `$_POST['skincareinuse']` are not arrays. Did you check their contents?

Comment: Implode works on array have you checked these are array. Try print_r($_POST['skincondition']);  just to check

Comment: @marcus, I guess you need to use `explode` here if you need to convert them to string or make the checkbox field name as `skincareinuse[]`

Comment: Yes i didnt set it as arrays in my html, my bad, but thanks guys :) And the implode works fine now, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML Part

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="skincondition[]" value="skincondition_1" />skincondition_1

<input type="checkbox" name="skincondition[]" value="skincondition_2" />skincondition_2

<input type="checkbox" name="skincondition[]" value="skincondition_3" />skincondition_3

<input type="checkbox" name="skincondition[]" value="skincondition_4" />skincondition_4

<input type="checkbox" name="skincondition[]" value="skincondition_5" />skincondition_5

<input type="submit" name="consultationbutton">
</form>
```

PHP code

```
if(isset($_POST['consultationbutton'])){        
$checkedcondition = implode(",",$_POST['skincondition']);
echo $checkedcondition;
}
```

working fine for me, please do share your HTML code so that i can tell you better.

Comment: It worked great now! I placed the name as name="skincondition" forgot to make it into an array, thanks for the help :)